# Handle CastError with Mongoose using Promises

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose (v. 3.8.8) to update some data of my model "Permission". Here is the schema:

```
var PermissionSchema = new Schema({

        name : { 
            type: String, required: true, index: true
        },
        httpVerb : { 
            type: String, required: true
        },
        url : { 
            type: String, required: true
        }
});

mongoose.model('Permission', PermissionSchema);
```

Now I have a function using promises in another module:

```
module.exports.updatePermission = function (id, updatedPermission) {

    var conditions = {_id: id};

    var promiseUpdate = Permission.update(conditions, updatedPermission).exec();

    logger.debug('this line is not executed when CastError occurs');

    var promiseFind = promiseUpdate.then(function (permission) {
        return Permission.findOne(conditions).exec();
    }).then(null, function (error) {
            logger.info('CastError does not get in here');
            logger.error(error);
            //error handled here
        });

    return promiseFind;
}
```

When I call that function with this example parameters:

```
id: 53496a2e1722ff2d1a55a4d2
updatedPermission: {name: 'this is my new name'}
```

**everything works fine** as that _id **does** already exist in the collection.

Now, when I use the following parameters passing on purpose an invalid and non-existent _id :

```
id: 53496a2e1722ff2d1a55a4d22
updatedPermission: {name: 'this is my new name'}
```

I get the following exception:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "53496a2e1722ff2d1a55a4d22" at path "_id"
    at ObjectId.cast (/home/jhon/environment/workspaces/nodejs-workspace/auth/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:116:13)
    at ObjectId.castForQuery (/home/jhon/environment/workspaces/nodejs-workspace/auth/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:165:17)
    at Query.cast (/home/jhon/environment/workspaces/nodejs-workspace/auth/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2291:32)
    at castQuery (/home/jhon/environment/workspaces/nodejs-workspace/auth/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2015:18)
    at Query.update (/home/jhon/environment/workspaces/nodejs-workspace/auth/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1704:21)
    at Function.update (/home/jhon/environment/workspaces/nodejs-workspace/auth/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1606:13)
    at Object.module.exports.updatePermission (/home/jhon/environment/workspaces/nodejs-workspace/auth/server/app/repository/auth/PermissionRepository.js:50:36)
```

I was expecting to get this error when the promise is rejected, that is, in the second "*then*" of the updatePermission function.

The question is: is this a bug of Mongoose? - How do I handle this without using try/catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found how to do it using promises in this particular case. Mongoose has a function findOneAndUpdate (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) which works as expected. The CastError is passed through the reject. This way I can handle the error without a try/catch block.

This is the code (PermissionRepository.js):

```
module.exports.updatePermission = function (id, updatedPermission) {
    var conditions = {_id: id};

    var promiseUpdate = Permission.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, updatedPermission).exec();

    return promiseUpdate;
}
```

The following code calls the previous one (CastError is handled in the second "then"):

```
module.exports.updatePermission = function (req, res) {
    var id = req.query.id;
    var updatedPermission = req.body;

    var permissionRepository = repositoryFactory.getPermissionRepository();
    var promise = permissionRepository.updatePermission(id, updatedPermission);

    promise.then(function (permission) {
        if (!permission) {
            res.status(404).json(Error.resourceNotFound);
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(permission);
        }
    }).then(null, function (error) {
            logger.error(error.stack);
            res.status(500).json(Error.databaseError(error.message, error));
        });
}
```

Now I'm pretty sure that there is a bug in the method update (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update). I'll report it.